# titanium - fire event - Listener callback is of a non-supported type: NSNull

Tags: titanium

I'm writing a simple script that simulates the change page.

```
    var square = $.UI.create('View',{page : info, classes : ["box"]});

    square.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify({title:e.source.page.title,page : e.source.page.id,menu:true});
            Ti.App.fireEvent('index:page',{title:e.source.page.title,page : e.source.page.id,menu:true});
        });
```

and in another controller I wrote

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('index:page',startup);
var startup = function(data){
    global_data = data;
    Alloy.Collections.menu.fetch();
    ...
    }
```

the problem is that when I tap into the "square" button, I got

```
Listener callback is of a non-supported type: NSNull
```

the line `Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify({title:e.source.page.title,page : e.source.page.id,menu:true});` gives me `{"title":"News","page":5,"menu":"true"}`

have no idea why. it seems like a parameter I pass to the startup function has null value, but the output doesn't say so.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the order of the declaration-invocation:

```
var startup = function(data){
    global_data = data;
    Alloy.Collections.menu.fetch();
    ...
    };
Ti.App.addEventListener('index:page',startup);
```

instead of

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('index:page',startup);
var startup = function(data){
    global_data = data;
    Alloy.Collections.menu.fetch();
    ...
    };
```